# Extract debugging information (STABS) from legacy Unix file format (a.out)

Tags: c, debugging, unix, gcc

I'm working for a software firm that is developing a software intended for teaching students about the Linux kernel. For some reason we've found ourselves in a situation where we need to write a program that reads in debug symbols from a.out files (the deprecated Unix executable format) and implement some functionalities of a debugger. The compiler that produces the symbols is GCC 1.4.
So what tools can I use to extract these debug symbols? It seems neither MinGW objdump nor readelf accept the file format. The operating system I'm using is Windows XP, by the way.

Cheers

Comment: I think you're stuck between a rock and a hard place. Your best bet is nominally to go back and find (the source for) a GDB that worked with the executables from GCC 1.4, but tracking that stuff down is going to be hard.  When was GCC 1.4 current?  Not this millennium, nor quite a lot of the last decade of the last millennium, I believe.  Why on earth are you having to deal with such a retrograde executable?  You're in for a tough time, I'm sorry to say — unless someone has a magic wand to wave for you.

Comment: my `objdump --help` output includes `a.out-i386-linux` in the list of supported targets. Perhaps that can help.